# PHP array_splice multi-dimentional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't think this is a duplicate, but maybe I'm just not using good keywords. I need to take a 2D array and add in another 2D array such that

```
$arr  = array(array(1,2), array(3,4), array(7,8));
$arr2 = array(array(5,6));
array_splice($arr, ?, ?, $arr2);
```

Would give me back

```
[0] => 1,2
[1] => 3,4
[2] => 5,6
[3] => 7,8
```

I'm at a loss at how to do this, as the documentation isn't clear how to not remove any of the array but still add to it.

Thanks.

Comment: [array_merge](http://uk1.php.net/array_merge) ?

Comment: No, they have to be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use array_splice(), then you want to insert at position `2` and use an offset of `0` (neither positive nor negative) so you don't remove any existing values but move them up in position:

```
$arr  = array(array(1,2), array(3,4), array(7,8));
$arr2 = array(array(5,6));
array_splice($arr, 2, 0, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge

```
<?php

$arr  = array(array(1,2), array(3,4), array(7,8));
$arr2 = array(array(5,6));
$result = array_merge($arr, $arr2);

print_r($result);
```

http://codepad.org/B0ckNCpM

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )
)
```

Comment: Then use [natsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) ;) or [another sorting algorithm](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: :) I would if Make Baker hadn't given me an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Array Merge Will do this for you.

LIVE TEST: https://eval.in/85459

```
$arr  = array(array(1,2), array(3,4), array(7,8));
$arr2 = array(array(5,6));
$arr = array_merge($arr,  $arr2);
print_r($arr);
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )

)
```

`array_splice()` is use for remove elements from an array and replace it with new elements.

Comment: You need to assign array_merge to a variable. Look at your output - it didn't include `$arr2`.